# Bluebird error warning a promise was created in handler... react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, bluebird

Error: 
`Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it`

It should be noted this error is thrown at the `logoutUser` function in the console.log, it says `at Object.logout`

I have tried many ways for fixing this and even have talked to some others before I came here for help. I have seen this error a lot and fixed it, but for some reason I can't seem to get it working. I know it is only a warning but I would like to have it fixed.

Code:

```
deleteProfile() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    const profile = this.props.profiles[id];
    const { currentUser } = this.props.user;

    if (currentUser.id !== profile.id) {
      swal({
        title: 'Oops...',
        text: 'You do not own this profile',
        type: 'error'
      });

      return;
    }

    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'Your Profile will be lost forever!',
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then(() => {
      const userPosts = this.props.post.all.filter(p => p.profile.id === profile.id);
      const userReplies = this.props.reply.all.filter(r => r.user.id === profile.id);
      userPosts.map(post => {
        this.props.deleteRecord(post);
      });
      userReplies.map(reply => {
        this.props.deleteReply(reply);
      });
      this.props
        .deleteProfile(profile)
        .then(data => {
          this.props.history.push('/');
          swal('Deleted!', 'Your Profile has been deleted.', 'success');
          return data;
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.props.logoutUser();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Attempted fixes:

```
.then( () => {
    this.props.logoutUser()
    .then( () => {
        this.props.history.push('/')
    })
})
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try returning `logoutUser` function like `return this.props.logoutUser()`?

Comment: That worked! Thank you, why can't I just do a return at the bottom? What does returning `logoutUser` do differently?